# Setting up an Android device under Linux for development, without root

Tags: android, root

Hello StackOverflowers,

I am eager to try out some Android programs on my tablet in the early phase. However, I do not have root access to the Linux machine I am using (OpenSUSE 12.1). Due to this, I am having trouble to let the system find my device.

This tutorial http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, as well as almost every post I can find online, do not mention ways to walk around the `51-android.rules` setting without root. Some post even mention that, to find the device, the `adb` command should be run with root.

Does this mean I have no hope of on-device debugging? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need root access for adb. Though for the device to be detected, AFAIK you need to add device details in `rules.d` .

If you have device and the computer on the same network, you could use adb over wifi. But to put the device in tcp mode , you need root access on phone or another computer where device can be detected.

Comment: Thanks @nandeesh! I never thought that would an option. From your advice, I found this post on [adb over tcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp). Though less convenient, things just worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your device doesn't have to be rooted. After you add your device in `51-android.rules`, make sure you restart adb server by using these commands:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

And one more thing, make sure you turn On `Debugging Mode`